# How to save the image file associated with user in springboot, thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to save the image file and the item details to mysql database, However i got an 
   error.
   I am using thymeleaf for the front end.

Here is my item upload form:

```
@GetMapping("/itemUploadForm")
public String itemUploadForm(Model theModel) {

    Item theItem = new Item();

    theModel.addAttribute("item", theItem);

    return "fileUploadForm";
}
```

This part is to process the image and the item details once taken from the user.

```
 @PostMapping("/itemUploadProcess")
    public String itemUploadProcess(@ModelAttribute("item") Item theItem,@RequestParam("imagefile") MultipartFile imageFile) throws Exception {
        String folder = "/photos";
        byte[] bytes = imageFile.getBytes();

        Path path = Paths.get(folder + imageFile.getOriginalFilename());
        Files.write(path, bytes);

        itemService.save(theItem);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

This is a class item.
   I dont know if the problem is in this properties or in mysql.
   I have mysql column for file set as imagefile blob not null;

```
    package com.rentyou.projectdemo.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    public String description;

    @Column(name = "conditiontype")
    public String type;

    @Column(name = "price")
    public String price;

    @Column(name = "contact")
    public String contact;

    @Column(name = "itemimage")
    public MultipartFile itemImage;


    public Item() {
    }



    public Item(String name, String description, String type, String price, String contact, MultipartFile itemImage) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.type = type;
        this.price = price;
        this.contact = contact;
        this.itemImage = itemImage;
    }



    public Item(int id, String name, String description, String type, String price, String contact,
            MultipartFile itemImage) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.type = type;
        this.price = price;
        this.contact = contact;
        this.itemImage = itemImage;
    }



    public MultipartFile getItemImage() {
        return itemImage;
    }



    public void setItemImage(MultipartFile itemImage) {
        this.itemImage = itemImage;
    }



    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(String contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }

}
```

This part is the form to take image file and the item details:

```
<form th:action="@{/itemUploadProcess}"
                     th:object="${item}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"
                class="form-control mb-4 col-4" placeholder="Name">

        <input type="text" th:field="*{description}"
                class="form-control mb-4 col-4" placeholder="Description">

        <input type="text" th:field="*{type}"
                class="form-control mb-4 col-4" placeholder="Condition">

        <input type="text" th:field="*{price}"
                class="form-control mb-4 col-4" placeholder="Price">

        <input type="text" th:field="*{contact}"
                class="form-control mb-4 col-4" placeholder="Contact">

        <input type="file" th:field="*{itemImage}" class="form-control mb-4 col-4" placeholder="Contact" name="imagefile">

        <button type="submit" class="btn btns-info col-2">Save</button>

    </form>
```

Comment: I suggest you start by writing tests to determine where the error is occurring.  You also have not given the error message in your post which makes it hard to determine what is wrong.

Comment: @Deadron 
These are the errors i am getting: 

On browser:

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun May 24 20:40:10 AEST 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).

Comment: @Deadron 

On a Eclipse console:
Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
  : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-05-24 20:40:10.441  INFO 7732 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 6 ms
2020-05-24 20:40:10.511  WARN 7732 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'imagefile' is not present]

Comment: Well from that error we know you are not properly submitting the file. You will need to show the code used to submit the file.  Either the html form or your http client code.

Comment: @Deadron

The code is already up there to submit a file..The form part.

Answer (score 0):

Remove that attribute `name="imagefile"` from your form.  Its giving the file the wrong name.   The th:field attribute will supply the correct name attribute.